# Javascript sorting Object dates

Tags: javascript, sorting, object

After looping I got following array. Is it possible to sort this from current date to latest.

```
//Sortering
    var arr = {};
    var key = "";
    var teller = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < schedule_id.length; i++) {

    //Ajax call maken
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.viewer.zmags.com/schedules/" + schedule_id[i] + "?key=" + api_key
    })
    //WdInit after 10 calls
    .done(function(data){

        //Check publicatieID is not null
        if (undefined === data.scheduleEntries[default_pub]|| null === data.scheduleEntries[default_pub]) {
        }
        else
        {       

            var key = schedule_id[teller];
            //loopen doorheen resultaat call
            $.each(data.scheduleEntries, function(index, entry){
                arr[key] = entry.startDate;
            })
        }   
        teller++;
    })
    }

arr: Object
7aaabbec: "2015-02-09T23:00:00.000Z"
31ba19e7: "2015-02-24T23:01:00.000Z"
31ff78e7: "2015-02-24T23:01:00.000Z"
159a11a7: "2015-02-10T23:01:00.000Z"
1339d0e9: "2015-02-17T23:01:00.000Z"
```

Code that I already got but error: Undefined is not a function

```
        arr.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a - b;
        });
```

Comment: what you mean by lover to higher ? in what basis ??

Comment: Well... can you tell us more about 'arr'

Comment: I will update my question

Comment: ok update your question based on your requirement, say clearly what did you want

Comment: Also... no you can not sort your `object`. It really does not make sense to sort `Objects`.

Comment: "most current" and "latest" date are the same thing...

Comment: You are trying to sort an Object's properties in order of their values. This doesn't make sense. Why not just put all the dates into an array and sort that? Or if you only need latest date then just figure that out when you loop through them the first time.

Comment: But yes... you can get the `Object` keys as a list then sort them... and then retrieve the attributes by calling `arr[ key ]` in sorted order.

Comment: Actually I need to sort the keys based on the dates. So I made a kind of HashMap and later I will use the key of the object

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By looping object, get all dates into array and sort them and make the object again

```
            var myObj = {
                '7aaabbec': "2015-02-09T23:00:00.000Z",
                '31ba19e7': "2015-02-24T23:01:00.000Z",
                '31ff78e7': "2015-02-24T23:01:00.000Z",
                '159a11a7': "2015-02-10T23:01:00.000Z",
                '1339d0e9': "2015-02-17T23:01:00.000Z"
            };
            var timeArray = [], newObj = {};
            for(var key in myObj){
              timeArray.push([key,myObj[key]]); 
            }
            timeArray.sort(function(a, b) {return new Date(a[1]) - new Date(b[1])});
            //console.log(timeArray);
            var j=0,k=1;
            for(var i=0;i<timeArray.length;i++){
              newObj[timeArray[i][j]] = new Date(timeArray[i][k]);
            }
            $("#result").html(JSON.stringify(newObj));
```

Working example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/syx9dd57/1/)

Comment: And by creating an object again, you're discarding the order. Yes, in practice this may often result in an "ordered object", simply due to implementation details. However, **nothing is guaranteeing the order of object properties.** You're relying on entirely undefined behaviour, which may or may not break at any time under certain circumstances.

Comment: Thanks, i didnt check on FF, while creating new object, order is changing. I am trying to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Objects have no order**. You cannot order an object. You'd have to turn this into an array first, which in turn cannot have arbitrary keys, but is orderable.

In Javascript:

- objects: key-value collections with undefined order
- arrays: lists with order, but without (meaningful) keys

Comment: You could create an Array of Objects and then sort that Array.

Comment: `[{id: '159a11a7', date: '2015-02-17T23:01:00.000Z'}, ..]` – that's the typical use case. (exempli gratia for @Chris)

Answer (score 0):

Use normal array to store the values so you can order them:

```
arr = [];
loopen doorheen resultaat call
$.each(data.scheduleEntries, function(index, entry){
     arr.push( {'key':key, 'date':entry.startDate} );
})

arr.sort(function(a, b){
    return a['date'] > b['date']; //this may need a better comparision...
});
```

**UPDATE:**
to extract the hash keys after the sorting just loop the array:

```
var sorted_keys = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  sorted_keys.push( arr[i] );
}
```

Comment: I used an Object as a kind of HashMap. The date part is just for the sorting but later I want to loop through the keys and uses this key of my functions. Is this possible in your solution?

Comment: you can loop them end extract the dates or keys after  the sorting, see the update

Comment: `array.push` is a method - you're assigning to it.

Answer (score 0):

First get keys from object, you use something like underscore.js for this:

```
var keyList = _.keys( arr );

// sort keyList
keyList = keyList.sort();

// Now, do anything by getting values for sorted keys
for ( key in keyList ) {
    console.log( arr[ key ] );
}
```

Just read your latest comment... for your case you can do it by first converting into a list of lists or list of key-val pairs

```
// convert into List of [ key, value ]
val pairList = _.pairs( arr );

// sort using values
pairList = pairList.sort( function( a, b ) {
    // use moment.js to get date functions
    var aMoment = moment( a[ 1 ] )
    var bMoment = moment( b[ 1 ] )

    // change based on reverse-sorted or sorted.
    return bMement.diff( aMement );
} );

// Now sorted use as you want
for ( keyVal in pairList ) {
    console.log( keyVal[ 0 ] + " -> " + keyVal[ 0 ] );
}
```